# I've had to box out a drain pipe from the roof and a steam riser: do I need to vent the box so that condensation doesn't accumulate inside?

Tags: plumbing, construction

Redoing my kitchen, two pipes run along the corner of a wall: a steam riser for the upstairs radiator and a down pipe for the gutter on the roof. They are within one or two inches of each other. I'm boxing them out and I'm wondering if they will create condensation inside the wall and if I need to worry about that.

It's not like these pipes have ever shown any condensation before, I'm just wondering if enclosing them might create a problem.

Comment: Your steam pipe _must_ be well insulated or you'd be burning yourself on it. It's not likely to cause more condensation once hidden behind some drywall than it is now.

Comment: Thanks. None of the steam risers are insulated except in the basement: none are in a place where people are likely to touch them. I've never seen it condense, actually, I thought perhaps closing it off might trap heat and therefore cause the down pipe of the gutter to condense.